# How to avoid Undefined offset error?

Tags: php

This is a part of my script:

```
$one = 0;
$two = 0;
$three = 0;

$data = 'a-b-c';

$data = explode("-", $data);
$one = $data[0];
$two = $data[1];
$three = $data[2];
```

No problems so far but **$data** sometimes can be

```
$data = 'a-b-c';
```

and sometimes

```
$data = 'a-b';
```

In case of `$data = 'a-b'`; I get **Undefined offset: 3** error. Is it some way how to avoid this error?

Comment: This is a design issue - your code will become messy and filled with conditionals; just rely on the array indexes.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wrap the assignment into an `if`-block:

```
if(isset($data[0])) {
    $one = $data[0];
}
```

...

This now checks if this array item isset, if not you just do not assign it and no error will show up.

Comment: There seems to be a missing parenthesis. I suggest `if(isset($data[0])) {`

Answer (score 5):

Assumes that at least one will always exist

```
$data = 'a-b';

list($one, $two, $three) = explode("-", $data . '-0-0');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php). Isset check if the variable exists.

```
// You can get rid of this since we set the default later if isset fail
/*
$one = 0;
$two = 0;
$three = 0;
*/

$data = 'a-b-c';

$data = explode('-', $data);
$one = (isset($data[0]) === TRUE ? $data[0] : 0);
$two = (isset($data[1]) === TRUE ? $data[1] : 0);
$three = (isset($data[2]) === TRUE ? $data[2] : 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

by using `isset` like `isset($data[0] == true)`

Comment: There seems to be a misplaced parenthesis. I suggest `isset($data[n]) == true`. Also, you can generally evaluate the truthiness just by doing `isset($data[n])`.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do like this:

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
$current = 0;
$index = 0;
while(isset($a[$index])) {
    $current = $a[$index];
    //... do something ...
    $index++;
}
```

This works!

Answer (score 0):

Since php 7.0 you can use the [null coalesce operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op).

All you need to do is to tell php what to do if `$data[2]` don't exists.

```
$three = $data[2] ?? "";
```